# How to fill iteratively in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to fill each row with the color grey.

What I first did:

```
ws['A9'].fill = greyFill
ws['B9'].fill = greyFill
ws['C9'].fill = greyFill
ws['D9'].fill = greyFill
ws['E9'].fill = greyFill
ws['F9'].fill = greyFill
ws['G9'].fill = greyFill
ws['H9'].fill = greyFill
ws['I9'].fill = greyFill
ws['J9'].fill = greyFill
ws['K9'].fill = greyFill

greyFill = PatternFill(start_color='bcbcbc',
                       end_color='bcbcbc',
                       fill_type='solid')
```

Now I did this:

```
import openpyxl
for row in ws.iter_rows('A9:L9'):
    for cell in row:
        ws[cell].fill = greyFill
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `iter_rows()` hasn't accepted ranges as parameters for a while, you need to provide the range boundaries as integers, though lower and upper limits for the worksheet will be applied if not provided. Use `ws["A9:L9"]` for ad hoc stuff. This is all covered in the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 2):

just change the code with below,

```
for rows in ws.iter_rows(min_row=9, max_row=9, min_col=1, max_col=11):
    for cell in rows:
        cell.fill = greyFill
```

accept the answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason my cells are still white

Comment: please try above code.